# Is there a way to find Data Deduplication in two columns of pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Data Deduplication in two columns of pandas. The data in the pandas might be misplaced and some are nulls.

```
Person    Name1        Name2  
0          Jet         NaN 
1          Edward      Lach  
2          NaN         Jet
3          Lach        Edward
```

Generating lists for Name1 and Name2 and see if they existed. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
set1,set2 = list(df["Name1"]),list(df["Name2"])



Expected
Person    SurName    FirstName  
0          Jet         NaN  
1          Edward      Lach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) with replace missing values by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), create DataFrame constructor for possible call [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with inverse mask by `~`:

```
mask = (pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['Name1','Name2']].fillna('missing'), axis=1), index=df.index)
          .duplicated())

df = df[~mask]
print (df)
   Person   Name1 Name2
0       0     Jet   NaN
1       1  Edward  Lach
```

Comment: Hi. Does this technique applies to numbers too? Suppose that we have 10 columns of numbers. Suppose that each row of numbers have the chances of duplication.

Comment: @MrSimple + I think yes, only better is change `.fillna('missing')` to some number like `.fillna(0)` or `.fillna(-1)`